# Take a backup of rake db migration. and command denied for rake db:migrate rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

I have db version 11. I want to move back to version 10 and add another version. But before that I want to take backup of version 11. How can I do that? I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 1.2.6.

```
rake db:migrate version=10
```

output: 
`rake aborted!
ActiveREcord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error SELECT command denied to user ''@'%' for column slot in table 'users'`

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a mighty old version of Rails you're using there!

You want to run a down migration to go back to a previous version:

```
rake db:migrate:down version=10
```

To make a backup first, use the client utility for your database.  For example, with MySQL:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: `rake db:migrate:down version=10` didn't work. gives error as `rake aborted!  Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate:down'`.